# MS Access to Oracle easy Conversion / Migration

Tags: oracle, ms-access, migration

Are there any good easy to use softwares to export Access Database files to an Oracle 11g database?

I know that this might not be the most usual case but applications grow, especially with old applications that uses old technologies such as Access in this case needs to be upgraded at some point.

Tutorials and articles regarding Access 2003 and 2007 migrations would be preffered.

There is a tool called mdbtools which would help by doing something like this:

```
for i in *.mdb;do mdb-schema $i oracle > $i.schema.sql;done
```

However I am on a Windows enviornment and mdbtools seems to be a Linux-only tool.

Comment: Er, Access is not aby any means an "old technology." Jet/ACE as data store can certainly be outgrown when an app gets more data and more users, but that isn't because it's "old technology" -- it's just that requirements have changed and outgrown the specs of the original data store.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Migration Workbench which comes with Oracle's (free) SQL Developer tool supports migrating from MS Access.  [Find out more](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/hol08/sqldev_migration/msaccess/migrate_microsoft_access_otn.htm).

**edit**

Because I don't use MS Access myself I missed an important point: SQL Developer doesn't support migration from Access 2007.  However, according [to this thread](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/message.jspa?messageID=3954365#3954365) on the OTN SQL Developer forum, it can be made to work with the latest version of SQL Developer (that is, 2.1).

Comment: Unfortunatly that Requires that you have Office 2003 and it doesn't really support all Access formats for example dates. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Could you provide a link explaining those points?  I admit I haven't undertaken an Access to Oracle migration, but the documentation suggests that they map MS Access dates to Oracle dates, and that it supports versions of Access dating back to 97.

Comment: By "doesn't support migration to Access 2007" do you mean that it doesn't support importing data into Oracle from ACCDB format databases?

Comment: Filip - Please be specific as to what formats don't work.   I find it hard to beleive that Access date fields can't be converted over to Oracle or any other database.  Same with other data formats.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah - thanks for letting me know. I've edited it with working link.